# Is questions related to contemporary acts. laws etc., are allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are many laws, acts etc., related to people, whose official religion is Hinduism in India.

Suppose, in scriptures, it is allowed to marry multiple ladies simultaneously. But, current Hindus in India cannot implement it due to Hindu marriage act.

Similarly, there may be many similarities or differences from scriptures to contemporary society.

Is it allowed to ask contemporary rules of Hindu people in India? If not, what is the reason for disallowing it?

Comment: In Kali Yug, people do not follow Shastras. They come up with their own rules based on 'democracy'. This is done in order to suit the degraded/animalistic nature of people. Dharmena Hinah Pashubhi Samanah. But most of these constitutional laws are not against Dharma. For e.g. adultery is no longer illegal. But no law can say that you MUST commit adultery. It just says that if you do commit it, that judge/police do not have the high moral ground to punish you, cos they themselves are degraded people.

Answer (score 2):

Laws in India such as Hindu Marriage Act, Hindu Inheritance Act etc are Hindu in name only. They are not based on Hindu customs or any shastras.

So I don't think questions related to contemporary laws in India are in scope